# Deep-Dream - load Re-trained Inception model obtained with transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-dream

I have repurposed an `Inception V3` network using the **transfer learning** method, following [this article](http://this%20article).

For that, I removed the final network layer, and fed hundreds of images of my face into the network.

A new model was then sucessfully generated: `inceptionv3-ft.model`

---

Now I would like to load this model and use its fixed weights to apply my face as a 'theme' on a input image, like `google-dream`.

For that I am using a `keras` program, which loads models like so:

```
from keras.applications import inception_v3

# Build the InceptionV3 network with our placeholder.
# The model will be loaded with pre-trained ImageNet weights.
model = inception_v3.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',
                                 include_top=False)
dream = model.input
```

> Full code here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/deep_dream.py

**So, how do I load and pass not a pre-trained but rather *my RE-trained model weights*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('inceptionv3-ft.model')
dream = model.input
```